# Pros/Cons on Lists with subsidiary objects

Tags: c#, list, design-patterns

I'm again in the position to figure a way out to handle lists with subsidiary objects on our business objects.

Actually, our code often looks like this:

```
public class Object
{
    private List<SubsidiaryObject> subsidiaryObjects = null;
    public List<SubsidiaryObject> SubsidiaryObjects
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.subsidiaryObjects == null)
            {
                this.subsidiaryObjects = DBClass.LoadListFromDatabase();
            }

            return this.subsidiaryObjects;
        }

        set
        {
            this.subsidiaryObjects = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The Con on this:

- The property is referenced in presentation layer and used for DataBinding. Releasing the reference to the actual list and replacing it with a new one will end in an referenced list in the GUI that does not have anything left with the list on the object.

The Pro on this:

- Easy way of reloading the list (just set the reference to null and then get it again).

I developed another class that uses the following pattern:

```
public class Object2
{
    private readonly List<SubsidiaryObject> subsidiaryObjects = new List<SubsidiaryObject>();
    public List<SubsidiaryObject> SubsidiaryObjects
    {
        get
        {
            return this.subsidiaryObjects;
        }
    }

    public void ReloadSubsidiaryObjects()
    {
        this.SubsidiaryObjects.Clear();
        this.SubsidiaryObjects.AddRange(DBClass.LoadListFromDatabase());
    }
}
```

Pro on this:

- Reference is continous.

The Con on this:

- Reloading the list is more difficult, since it just cannot be replaced, but must be cleared/filled with reloaded items.

What is your preferred way, for what situations?

What do you see as Pro/Con for either of these to patterns?

Since this is only a general question, not for a specific problem, every answer is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need the caller to be able to modify the list? If not you should consider returning `IEnumerable<T>` or `ReadOnlyCollection` instead. And even if you do, you will probably be better off making cover versions for `Add`/`Remove` so you can intercept modifications. Handing a reference to internal state is not a good idea IMO.

A third option would be to go with option 2, but to create a new instance of the `Object2` type each time you need to repopulate the list. Without additional context for the question, that is the option I would select, but there may be reasons why you would want to hold on to the original instance.

Comment: Indeed, the main reason to hold the original instance is, it is an subsidiary object itself... with exception on the top-level.